# How to read cookie in nginx

Tags: cookies, nginx, proxy, proxypass, httpcookie

I am very novice in UI programming and in nginx. Sorry if the question is dumb. Also I tried almost all the answers present in stackoverflow questions similar to this but nothing helped me to solve this issue

**What I need to do :**

Check whether a cookie named "AUTH_COOKIE" present. If its present proxy_pass to a site1. Else proxy_pass site2. For this I need to read the cookie.

**What I tried :**

I tried to read the cookie as $cookie_AUTH_COOKIE, but it doesn't provide me any result. I tried reading using $http_cookie. No use with that as well

I tried following the gist present over here https://gist.github.com/rnorth/2031652 and https://gist.github.com/NickSto/6920790. But no use.

So now I just tried to read the cookie value and return it using [echo](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule). Response does not contain value for my cookie.

Here is nginx config that I have did using echo

```
server {
    listen       3001;
    server_name  <my_host>;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    # include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    # set $auth_cookie "check";
    if ($http_cookie ~* "AUTH_COOKIE=([a-z0-9]+)(?:;|$)") {
        set $auth_cookie $1;
    }
    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        echo "This is a test from $host with $auth_cookie. Cookie $cookie_AUTH_COOKIE. Referer $http_referer";
    }
}
```

When I invoke this via [advanced rest client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) , I get the response as

`This is a test from localhost with . Cookie . Referer`

You can see that $auth_cookie, $cookie_AUTH_COOKIE and $http_referer are not returned.

Here is the screen shots my rest client
[image: Request]
[image: Respnse]

What am I missing here. Do I need to import any module to read cookie?

Comment: There is not cookie in request headers on your screenshot

Comment: ```AUTH_COOKIE=test```. This is supposed to be cookie. Or is there any other way to send cookie

Comment: Probably you can't set arbitrary headers from browser. Try to use console tools, like curl. Check this command `curl -v -H 'Cookie: AUTH_COOKIE=test' http://myhost:3001`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now with [postman interceptor] (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) I am able to pass cookies

Comment: Can you just add an answer with the above comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cookie in request headers on your screenshot.

Probably you can't set arbitrary headers with this tool. Try to use console tools, like `curl` or `GET`. Check this command `curl -v -H 'Cookie: AUTH_COOKIE=test' http://myhost:3001`